# JSF - ViewScope - It just work with AJAX calls?

Tags: jsf-2, view-scope

I am using JSF 2.1 and PrimeFaces 3.5 and I have some questions about the ViewScope scope.

This scope should work while I use the same page, right? But, everytime I refresh my page the container just create another instance of my ManagedBean and I lose all my data. Why? By the way, it JUST work if I use Ajax. am I right?

Comment: indeed if you refresh the page, a new bean is created. that is expected behavior. I don't understand your question about ajax..

Answer (score 1):

A viewscoped bean will be the same as long as you post to the same page. AJAX or not.

A refresh in the browser is handled as a new page.